# Почему гауптвахта — «губа»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, выбор-слов, история

*"Губа" не дура. Армейская гауптвахта, история применения которой в России насчитывает уже 298 лет, в ближайшее время будет вновь узаконена.*
[Дисциплинарный арест](http://legalru.ru/document.php?id=24361)

*Наиболее используемым видом наказания было содержание недисциплинированного солдата на гауптвахте ("губе"), куда его мог отправить на энное количество суток командир своим решением.*
[Дисциплина и дисциплинарные наказания в армии](http://twower.livejournal.com/688636.html)

А почему гауптвахта — "губа"? Откуда и когда появилось такое название?

Answer (score 3):

Малограмотные солдаты еще при царе называли гауптвахту  "губвахта". А там и ещё сократили, получилась  "губа".

Comment: ответ интересный, но есть ли ссылки на источники? или это одна из версий?

Comment: Нет, ссылок нет, так что одна из версий.

Comment: Насчёт «малограмотных солдат при царе»... Первое: рекруты в ходе службы могли дослужиться до офицерского чина и стать дворянами. Второе: регулярная армия возникла при императоре Петре I.

Comment: Я ж не утверждаю, что все были неграмотны, грамотные правильно произносили, а кто из простых, не знающих иностранных языков, те произносили, как слышалось. Не поняла Ваших возражений, у Вас ответ похож - созвучие.ау-у

Comment: @Людмила А можно на меня(военного, сына  и внука военного) и ссылаться, как на живое свидетельство. С самого малого возраста от множества не очень и очень грамотных военных людей никогда не слышал, произношения по писаному - "гауптвахта". В этом дифтонге "ау" всегда короткое "а" почти не слышалась. Зато "т" вообще не произносилось, а в результате озвончения "п" от стоящей позади "в" выходило именно "гуубвахта", такое вот профессиональное произношение. Иного не слышал никогда.

Answer (score 1):

Армейская «губа» — камеры для временного содержания (и офицеров, в том числе) — служба при комендатуре (*haupt* = главный), где нерадивого военного за несколько дней и ночей ставят на место, невзирая на прежние заслуги, вмиг сбивают с него всякую спесь.

Наименование такое — не от смысла, а лишь от созвучия с первой, практически безударной, частью заимствованного слова, где АУ приравнено к У. Однако, слегка притягивая за уши (при том, что каждый, оказавшийся там считает себя невиновным страдальцем), можно связать институт «губы» с клубом обиженных, на которых воду возят. Была же поговорка «Губы толще, брюхо тоньше»! Искать личную выгоду (*раскатал губы*) и хотеть большего всегда было и будет чревато поражением в правах (*получил по губам*).